# Users can still search Accounts even when sharing settings prevents them

Tags: sharing-rule

I have this situation.

In our sharing settings we have Account Sharing Rules that says something like:

Rule 01:
If an account record has a value 'ABC' in field01, then ONLY users with Role, 'RoleABC' can see them.

Rule 02:
If an account record has a value 'DEF' in field01, then ONLY users with Role, 'RoleDEF' can see them.

However, user with RoleABC tried to search the Account Phone Number (ex. 12345) and he got two Accounts that has 'ABC' and 'DEF' values in their field01 respectively. (Note: Both Accounts have the same phone numbers)

Ex: Search Results for Phone Number - 12345

Acct01:
field01 - ABC
Phone Number - 12345

Acct02:
field01 - DEF
Phone Number - 12345

Based on the Sharing Rules, User of RoleDEF should not see Acct01, but in the actual search result, he saw both Acct01 and Acct02.

Can anyone give me some idea why this is happening?

We really think that the fix for this is to recalculate the Sharing Rules for Account since Rule02 is a new rule. However, since this is in our Production, I'm kind of hesitant to do the recalculation until I've exhausted all other explanations.

Thanks.

Comment: It's important to remember that sharing rules are always *grants* of access, and never *take away* other access. The user may have other reasons to access Acct01, like the role hierarchy or an implicit share based on owning a Contact or Case associated with it. If you inspect the Sharing window for the Account, what do you see?

Comment: If you have created that rule newly or deployed that in production, then without performing recalculation, existing record visibility will not get changed. I am assuming OWD of Account is Private.

Comment: May be user is owner of the DEF record or record is shared with him in other way like using Apex sharing, Role hierarchy or user have view all permission

Comment: @DavidReed Thank you so much for that one. That is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that sharing rules are always grants of access, and never take away other access. For that reason, I don't believe that recalculating sharing rules will have any effect unless you also changed some rule providing access to be narrower.

The user likely has other reasons to access Acct01, like the role hierarchy or an implicit share based on owning a Contact or Case associated with it.

You can review these visibility sources by inspecting the Sharing window for the Account.